# Occasionally disabling Pyramid middleware

Tags: pyramid

**Note**: If it's any help, I'm using Pyramid 1.3.2.  I know it's a little out of date, I would prefer not to update right away, but I might be able to force an update if the latest version provides better support for this use case.

The Pyramid-based application I'm working on has a strict authorization policy: **all** calls **must** be authenticated.  Since 1) it's tedious to add this manually on every request handelr; and 2) we don't want anybody to "forget" adding authentication, we enforce this server-wide using a simple Pyramid middleware (tween) that verifies all incoming requests.

Recently, this restriction has been slightly relaxed: occasionally, some resources should support (safe & idempotent) `GET` without authentication.

It seems this is directly opposed to the usual design ideas behind authentication in most web frameworks (optional authentication), so I can't get it to work quite as expected.

**QUESTION**: What is the correct approach to implementing an authorization middleware that authenticates & verifies authorization by default, but can be disabled on a view-by-view basis?

---

So far, I've tried adding a simple decorator like so:

```
def allows_anonymous_access(f):
  f.allows_anonymous_access = True; return f

@allows_anonymous_access
def my_pyramid_view(request):
  # ...
```

In my middleware, I would like to use it like this:

```
def authorization_middleware(handler, registry):
  def verify_authorization(request):
    # Identify the user making the request.  Make sure we get the
    # user's identify if provided, even when the request handler
    # allows anonymous access.
    try:
      request.principal = extract_user(request)
    except InvalidCredentials, error:
      if getattr(handler, 'allows_anonymous_access', False):
        request.principal = AnonymousUser()
      else:
        raise HTTPUnauthorized(...)
    # Invoke the handler.
    return handler(request)
  # Middleware that will pre/post-process the request.
  return authorization_middleware
```

However, when the middleware executes, `handler` is not my view.  It happens to be a  bound method (`pyramid.router.Router.handle_request`) which does not provide me access to the view callable, meaning I cannot access the flag set by the middleware.

Comment: Pyramid has its own auth system. I would highly recommend trying to use it instead of writing your own. What you have requested is very simple inside of the framework, likely less code than you have pasted in this question. The answer provided by Piotr is correct, but you'll have difficulty using it without configuring an ACL and authn/authz policies. There are several other questions here on SO discussing how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want `pyramid.config.set_default_permission(permission)`. From [docs](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.4-branch/api/config.html?highlight=set_default_permission#pyramid.config.Configurator.set_default_permission):

> Adding a default permission makes it unnecessary to protect each view
>   configuration with an explicit permission, unless your application
>   policy requires some exception for a particular view.
>
> If a default permission is in effect, view configurations meant to
>   create a truly anonymously accessible view (even *exception view* views)
>   *must* use the value of the permission importable as
>   `pyramid.security.NO_PERMISSION_REQUIRED`. When this string is used as
>   the `permission` for a view configuration, the default permission is
>   ignored, and the view is registered, making it available to all
>   callers regardless of their credentials.

Answer provided by *raydeo_* on #pyramid freenode IRC channel.