# Pyramid - How do I create a route that avoids authentication

Tags: python, authentication, pyramid, pylons

So I have a pyramid web app and authentication is working great. If a user has not logged in and tries to visit a certain route, then are redirected to the login page.  Now, however, I have a route that I would like to add for which I want to make sure that authentication is not required.  For this route only, I would like the view to be rendered even if the user has not logged in.  How can I accomplish this?

Comment: how is your authentication configured?

Comment: using AuthTktAuthenticationPolicy with callback=groupfinder.  groupfinder is a function is a security module that we have.  I'm guessing I have to edit that function to return something like "okay" for the particular route I have in mind.

Comment: how are you checking in your view whether a user has been logged in or not? are you using `permission`?

Comment: Yes.  I figured out that I have to set a special permission called "no permission required"

Comment: Related: [Occasionally disabling Pyramid middleware](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17030095/95735)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@view_config(route_name='home', permission=pyramid.security.NO_PERMISSION_REQUIRED)
def open_view(request):
    # ...
```

This will disable authorization for the view.